# Add confirm (yes no) in submit with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code submit with preventDefault. this my code

```js
 //submit terima barang
            $("form.form_terima").submit(function (event) {
                if (confirm('Submit Terima Barang ?')) {
                    $(".loader").show();
                    //disable tombol submit supaya tidak reload
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'po_req/po_req_crud.php', //type='add_terima'
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                          //action if success
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

but, it's not working. how to solve it ? thanks buddy :)

Comment: Not working how exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the `event.preventDefault()` will run only when the user has clicked "OK"/"Yes". If the user has clicked "No", then the form will submit.

You must add the `event.preventDefault()` outside of the `if` block to make it work as you expect.

```
$("form.form_terima").submit(function (event) {
    if (confirm('Submit Terima Barang ?')) {
        $(".loader").show();
         //disable tombol submit supaya tidak reload
         var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
         $.ajax({
            url: 'po_req/po_req_crud.php', //type='add_terima'
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //action if success
            }
        });
    }

    // prevent default regardless of user's response
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Iblamefish, it's work, before i forgot put `submit` inside `<form></form>` #lol. And your ` event.preventDefault();` put outside `if` is useful. thanks so much